# How to add custom view links to wp-admin/post.php?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I have a Custom Post Type page where i want to retain the default 'edit' post screen. In my case i add csv data to the post.content area, and i've custom actions to process and save this data to a custom meta-style db table.

Once the post csv data has been loaded, i'd like to have URL/forms/something on the post page which allows the admin user to change the view of the data.

My question - is it possible to add custom links to the horizontal area where the 'Add New' button is shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no hook to add the button there, but you can write a patch using JS code.

Please check here:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/32545